# Angular styleUrls directory instead of files

Tags: angular, components

[image]

I currently paste  all the stylesheets of my style folder into styleUrls. Is there a way not to hardcode those Urls and do it dynamically? For example: use all stylesheets of the directory ./styles/

```
styleUrls: ['./styles/]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `constants.ts` inside that you can do something like this.

constants.ts

```
export const CONSTANTS = {
    STYLES_SHARED:[
    'styles/test.css',
    'styles/test2.css',
    'styles/test3.css',
    'styles/test4.css',
    'styles/test5.css',
    'styles/test6.css',
    'styles/test7.css',
    'styles/test8.css',
  ]
};
```

Then import this constants whereever you want to prevent code duplication.

```
styleUrls: CONSTANTS.STYLES_SHARED
```

method 2:

If these styles are shared by every component in your angular project, please add the css files to your angular.json, they will be included for all files!

```
styles": [
  "src/styles.css",
  "src/more-styles.css",
  { "input": "src/lazy-style.scss", "inject": false },
  { "input": "src/pre-rename-style.scss", "bundleName": "renamed-style" },
]
```

reference here: [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#style-script-config)

Comment: thank you for your answer. But this way I still have to hardcode the urls. My goal is just to define the directory to the folder which contains all the css files. So that I don´t always have to define the urls to every css file.

Comment: @user16405471 Then specify in angular.json, check my last two lines, that will apply the styles, also supports globs like 'styles/**/*.css'